# Convert Matrix to JSON - PHP- ZF

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, matrix

I want to convert an array to JSON array to process this information with JS, but when converting get an unexpected result "bool (false)" should be a JSON

```
$datos = Array(
                    'caso' => $datoscaso,
                    'seguimiento' => $datosseguimiento
                );
```

$datoscaso; // is a array

$datosseguimiento // is a array

var_dump $datos;

```
array(2) {
  ["caso"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(7) {
      ["numero_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["fecha_inicio"]=>
      string(10) "2014-06-16"
      ["fecha_fin"]=>
      string(10) "2014-07-16"
      ["tipo_caso"]=>
      string(14) "Otros procesos"
      ["observaciones"]=>
      string(24) "Informacion sobre el sistema"
      ["cod_beneficiario"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["Estado_caso"]=>
      string(7) "Abierto"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["numero_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "27"
      ["fecha_inicio"]=>
      string(10) "2014-07-04"
      ["fecha_fin"]=>
      NULL
      ["tipo_caso"]=>
      string(24) "Tramites administrativos"
      ["observaciones"]=>
      string(25) "Otro caso nuevo de prueba"
      ["cod_beneficiario"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["Estado_caso"]=>
      string(7) "Abierto"
    }
  }
  ["seguimiento"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(14) {
      ["id_seguimiento"]=>
      string(2) "15"
      ["fecha_seguimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2014-06-16"
      ["observaciones_seguimiento"]=>
      string(24) "Informaci�n sobre el sistema"
      ["num_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["cod_entidad"]=>
      string(1) "4"
      ["cod_dependencia"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["cod_administrativo_bienestar"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["numero_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["fecha_inicio"]=>
      string(10) "2014-06-16"
      ["fecha_fin"]=>
      string(10) "2014-07-16"
      ["tipo_caso"]=>
      string(14) "Otros procesos"
      ["observaciones"]=>
      string(24) "Informacion sobre el sistema"
      ["cod_beneficiario"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["Estado_caso"]=>
      string(7) "Abierto"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(14) {
      ["id_seguimiento"]=>
      string(2) "16"
      ["fecha_seguimiento"]=>
      string(10) "2014-07-04"
      ["observaciones_seguimiento"]=>
      string(25) "Otro caso nuevo de prueba"
      ["num_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["cod_entidad"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["cod_dependencia"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["cod_administrativo_bienestar"]=>
      string(1) "3"
      ["numero_radicado"]=>
      string(2) "26"
      ["fecha_inicio"]=>
      string(10) "2014-06-16"
      ["fecha_fin"]=>
      string(10) "2014-07-16"
      ["tipo_caso"]=>
      string(14) "Otros procesos"
      ["observaciones"]=>
      string(24) "Informacion sobre condor"
      ["cod_beneficiario"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["Estado_caso"]=>
      string(7) "Abierto"
    }
  }
}
```

I use:

```
$json = Zend_Json::encode($datos);
echo $json;
var_dump($json);
```

**Print:** `"bool(false)"`

Comment: Have you tried good ol `json_encode()`?

Comment: TheodoreEnderby whit json_encode()  Print: "bool(false)"

=(

Answer (score 0):

Zend_Json is based on PHP json_encode, which needs data in UTF-8 codepage.

I can see characters out of UTF-8 in one of your array strings:

```
  ["observaciones_seguimiento"]=>
  string(24) "Informaci�n sobre el sistema"
```

Convert all values in array before treating them with Zend_Json::encode(). You can use [utf8_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I set in the configuration in Zend Framework this:

**File:** /application/configs/application.ini

```
resources.db.params.charset = "utf8"
```